# Unable to get payload response when payload length size is greater than 1000K.(Coap)

Tags: python-3.x, iot, coap

I am using Coapthon and Helperclient libraries to get, put, post the data.
I am using below mentioned code line to get the payload. it is working fine without any issue if pauload length size is not more than 1000.

```
response = self.client.get(path_check, timeout=30)
```

```
Jun 21, 2020 5:56:11 PM com.coap.dtls.test.ExampleDTLSClient$1 receiveData
INFO: received response, length53, hex payload:
```

But in some cases payload size is high "length1386", and it failed to get the payload:

```
Jun 21, 2020 5:56:21 PM com.coap.dtls.test.ExampleDTLSClient$1 receiveData
INFO: received response, length1386, hex payload:
```

And displays below mentioned error:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'payload'

Can anyone help he how can I get high length payload?
I am using python scripts and copathon libraries to achive it.

```
response = self.client.get(path_check, timeout=30)
```

Comment: You might get more helpful answers if you added more information around the errors you receive. At very least, look at the backtrace of the AttributeError and make sure that the lines in your code where the exception came from (ie. the frame of the backtrace that is your code) is part of the "what I did so far" portion of your question. It also often helps to include the stack trace as a whole.

Comment: Your title contains "1000K". So do you mean 1,000 Bytes or 1,000,000 Bytes? For the later, a timeout of 30 (seconds?) may just be too small. Start with a much larger one to get a time and then use that time plus a time buffer.

Answer (score 0):

CoAP is limited in its message size to a single UDP packet.

Usually, when the maximum size is exceeded, server and client fall back to what is called block-wise transfer. This allows transferring almost arbitrarily sized payloads.

In this concrete case, it appears on first glance that you are trying to access the response payload as a single response message's `.payload`, which does not exist because there is no single response message – but the block layer of CoAPython should take care of that. You may have run into a bug in the library implementation, which is easiest discussed [at its issue tracker](https://github.com/Tanganelli/CoAPthon/issues).

Comment: thanks @chrysn for updated. So there any alternative for now so that I can move ahead. Because of this I am stuck and unable to move forward.

Comment: There are other CoAP libraries in Python around (I maintain one of them), but you would probably make easier progress if you update your post with more details on what you did (see comment on the post: Add the code that actually cause the error, a backtrace, and possibly link to where you host the current version).